# recursive python triangle joined by new line

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I wrote this code for a recursive triangle assignment. I've taken on the challenge of adjusting my code to return just a single string joined by new lines.

```
def triangle(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return ""
    p = triangle(n-1)
    p = p + "*"
    print(p)
    return p

triangle(5)
```

I would like to get it to return "*\n**\n***\n****\n*****"

I'm just having a hard time making the changes I need.

Comment: Do you want to print `\n` as it is or as new line?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return a string, you'll have to remove the `print` calls from your function. As an aside, when writing recursive functions in general, you can/should avoid variable reassignment

```
def triangle (n):
  if n == 0:
    return ""
  else:
    return triangle (n - 1) + ("*" * n) + "\n"

print(triangle(5))
# *
# **
# ***
# ****
# *****
#
```

This does result in a trailing `\n` at the end of the string though. If you'd like to avoid this, you'll have to write an additional case when `n == 1`

```
def triangle (n):
  if n == 0:
    return ""
  elif n == 1:
    return "*"
  else:
    return triangle (n - 1) + "\n" + ("*" * n)

print(triangle(5))
# *
# **
# ***
# ****
# *****
```

Otherwise, another way is to build a list of the triangle rows and use `"\n".join` to insert a newline between each row

```
def triangle (n):
  def aux (acc, n):
    if n == 0:
      return acc
    else:
      return aux (["*" * n] + acc, n - 1)
  return "\n".join(aux([], n))

print(triangle(5))
# *
# **
# ***
# ****
# *****
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I'll have to do some reading on auxiliary helpers, now.

Comment: @wazawai it's a pretty generic thing to search for – simply put, an *auxiliary* function is one that is used only by another function to complete a specific task – we wouldn't want a user calling our auxiliary function manually – that's why `aux` is defined *inside* of `triangle` so that only `triangle` has access to use it

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that strings can be multiplied (repetitive concatenation) in python.

```
def triangle(n):
    return '\n'.join(['*'*i for i in range(1,n+1)])
```

Comment: I see some of my answer inspired your changes ^_^ Nice work